# What kind of random walk can lead to a lognormal distribution in the limit?

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, binomial-coefficients, normal-distribution, random-walk

For the binominal random walk with step sizes:
$S_i = \begin{cases}
 &+1  &\text{probability} &p, \\
  &-1  &\text{probability} &q=1-p
\end{cases}$

Let $T_n = \sum_{i=1}^mS_i$ be the displacement after a fixed, not random, number of steps $n$.

then the probability distribution:  $P(T_n=t)$ will approach a normal distribution when $n$ is large.

My question is, what kind of random walk (maybe with different step sizes, different probability) can generate a lognormal distribution in the limit ?

Comment: Log normal distribution is typically a result of a random product, not a random sum

Comment: But is there any way to generate log normal distribution as some kind of "random sum" ?

Comment: you can create a random sum and exponentiate it.

Comment: @user619894 what do you mean " exponentiate it" ?

Comment: I mean $e^{T_n}$

Comment: Are there anyway to DIRECTLY generate a log normal distribution as some kind of random walk, for example, with different step size, different probability for each step ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.

Comment: Here is what I *do* know: the distribution generated by an uncorrelated random walk is the convolution of the pdf's of all the steps, so you are looking for a RW such the the convolution of the single step pdf with the log normal pdf is still a log normal pdf. I believe this property is called "infinitely divisible". I have found this on the internet:https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03461238.1977.10405635?journalCode=sact20

Comment: @user619894 Thank you for pointing out the infinitely divisible property of lognormal distribution.

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is a fairly well-known solution to this problem which is called the Metropolis algorithm. This is one of the most common Markov Chain Monte Carlo methods. The idea is to make the random walk $(T_n)$ a Markov Chain such that the desired log-normal distribution is the unique stationary distribution for $(T_n)$. Then $T_n$ will be approximately log-normal distributed for large $n$.

Let $f$ denote the density of the log-normal distribution with some fixed parameters $\mu\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\sigma^2>0$. That is,
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{x\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{(\log x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)&\text{if }x>0, \\
0&\text{if }x\leq0.
\end{cases}
$$
Moreover, let $(U_n)$ and $(Z_n)$ be two independent sequences of i.i.d. random variables such that $U_1\sim U(0,1)$ and $Z_1\sim N(0,1)$. Now, put $T_0:=1$ and define for $n\geq1$:
$$
T_n:=
\begin{cases}
T_{n-1}+Z_n&\text{if }U_n\leq\frac{f(T_{n-1}+Z_n)}{f(T_{n-1})}, \\
T_{n-1}&\text{if }U_n>\frac{f(T_{n-1}+Z_n)}{f(T_{n-1})}.
\end{cases}
$$
To get closer to the formulation in the question we can also write:
$$
T_n:=
\begin{cases}
T_{n-1}+Z_n&\text{with probability }1\wedge\frac{f(T_{n-1}+Z_n)}{f(T_{n-1})}, \\
T_{n-1}&\text{with probability }1-\left(1\wedge\frac{f(T_{n-1}+Z_n)}{f(T_{n-1})}\right).
\end{cases}
$$
So the steps in this random walk are either $0$ or a realization of the $N(0,1)$-distribution. The probabilities which determine which of these steps to take depend on the current position, i.e. $T_n$, and the position we would go to if we were to take the $N(0,1)$ step, i.e. $T_{n-1}+Z_n$.

Comment: thank you for pointing out Metropolis algorithm. In you above statement, for each step, do we need to choose a $U_n$ and a $Z_n$ at the same time ?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by choosing at the same time? The important thing is that they are independent.

Comment: thank you. I am not familiar with this algorithm. Initial $T_0 = 1$, if $Z_1 = -100$, will this lead $T_1 < 0 $ ? or such situation is prohibited in above algorithm ?

Comment: If $T_0=1$ and $Z_1=-100$, then $f(T_0+Z_1)=0$ which means that $T_1=T_0$ with probability 1. The algorithm only allows $T_n$ to take values where $f$ is positive.

Comment: The idea of the algorithm is: In each iteration a new state $T_{n-1}+Z_n$ is suggested. This is accepted or rejected and the probabilities of these two scenarios depend on the ratio $f(T_{n-1}+Z_n)/f(T_{n-1})$.

Comment: Thank you. Can you also take a look of another related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4286980/what-kind-of-random-walk-can-generate-a-distribution-similar-to-exp-e2x-i ?

Comment: It seems like another job for the Metropolis algorithm. The great thing about this algorithm is that the density of the desired limit only shows up in the ratio $f(T_{n-1}+Z_n)/f(T_{n-1})$. Hence, it is sufficient to know the density up to scaling.

Comment: to clarify, even though $Z_n$ is an  i.i.d. random variable, but each step is NOT independent from previous step, is it  correct ?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: Thank you. Does $Z_n$ have to be  $N(0,1)$-distribution ? or  can it be some other types of distribution ?

Comment: The $Z_n$ can have another distribution. Depending on which limit you want, some distributions will work better (faster convergence) than others. The normal distribution was just an example.

Comment: Thank you.  I assume that  it has been proved mathematically rigorously that $T_n$ will (weakly) converge  to the targeted distribution. Is it ?

Comment: Yes. Have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis–Hastings_algorithm). What you should note is that using a different distribution for the $Z_n$ might require you to calculate the probabilities a little different. Under "Formal derivation" you see the general form of the probabilities.

Comment: Thank you. Can you take a related question ?https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4289229/what-is-the-distribution-of-the-output-of-metropolis-hastings-algorithm-at-a-fix

Comment: I have read the question, and my guess is that the distribution of $T_n$ is too complicated to write down. What we can say is that it converges to the target distribution as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: @ jakobdt, thank you. "What we can say is that it converges to the target distribution as n→∞." Is it a property of Metropolis algorithm ? I had searched online, could not find this  statement. Can you provide a link or a reference for this statement ?

Comment: I own the book "Stochastic Simulation: Algorithms and Analysis" by Asmussen and Glynn. They cover the algorithm (including proofs) in Chapter XIII.3. Since this is my go-to reference for these things I am not familiar with some freely available PDF or similar.

Comment: thank you. I will take a look of the book.

Comment: For any target distribution, the distribution of $T_n$ will converge to it. In the algorithm, $Z_n$ follows Gaussian distribution.  So the $T_n$ can be considered as a "summation of Gaussian random variables", but why is the summation is NOT a Gaussian random variable ? Intuitively, how to understand this ? is it because Accept or Reject mechanism in the algorithm completely distorts the "summation of Gaussian distribution should be Gaussian" this principle  ?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Since not all steps are accepted we do not get convergence to the normal distribution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130950/discussion-between-david-and-jakobdt).

Answer (score 1):

$T_0 = 1, T_{n+1} = \begin{cases}
 &2 * T_n  &\text{probability} &p, \\
  &1/2 * T_n  &\text{probability} &q=1-p
\end{cases}$

additive version:
$S_0 = 1, S_{n+1} = \begin{cases}
 &T_n  &\text{probability} &p, \\
  &-1/2 * T_n  &\text{probability} &q=1-p
\end{cases}$

main challenge is that you have to adjust step size $S_n$ to place where you are now $T_n$, here I used factor $2$ but you can tweek this parameter to get desired result

this version should produce skewed displacement
$T_0 = 1, S_{n} = \begin{cases}
 &2/n  &\text{probability} &p, \\
  &-1/n  &\text{probability} &q=1-p
\end{cases}$

Comment: Thank you. This is "multiplicative". Is it possible to get an "additive" random walk ?

Comment: @david take a look on new version

Comment: for a simple random walk, $S_n$ can be written as the summation of all previous steps. For your version, can we still considered as $S_n$ as the summation all previous steps ? I think so, but in this case, each step is NOT independent random variables, am I right ? Your version of random walk is still a Markov process, is it ? But it is NOT a stationary process, is it ?

Comment: @david yes these are dependent on past, I have added one more idea

Comment: Thank you again. For your new idea, I tried first a few $n$, it seems that they can NOT form a log-normal distribution. Can you show that this will generate a log-normal distribution ?

Comment: @david sorry I forgot that it had to generate log-normal distribution, it was a mistake from my side

Comment: for your new idea, is there a formula for the distribution it will generate ?

Comment: @david no, this idea was only to give example for generating skewed distribution

Comment: thank you again.