# How to generate this distribution?

Tags: probability

For the simple random walk with step sizes:
$$S_i = \begin{cases}
 &+1  &\text{probability} &p=1/2, \\
  &-1  &\text{probability} &q=1/2
\end{cases}$$

Let $T_n = \sum_{i=1}^mS_i$ be the displacement after a fixed number of steps $n$. Then the probability distribution:  $P(T_n=t)$ will approach a normal distribution, a scaled version of $\exp{(-x^2)}$ , when $n$ is large.

**Question:** What kind of random walk (maybe with different step sizes, different probability) can generate a distribution similar to $\exp(-e^{2x})$  in the limit (with some scale factors) ?

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in an answer to [a similar post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4226299/what-kind-of-random-walk-can-lead-to-a-lognormal-distribution-in-the-limit/4286686?noredirect=1#comment8924089_4286686): The random walk resulting from the Metropolis algorithm could be what you are looking for.

Comment: Can you provide some details on how to choose the probability and step size for each step assuming that the final distribution is $c\exp(-ae^{2x})$ where $c, a$ are some scaling constants ?

Comment: You use the same approach as for the log-normal limit. The only difference is that this time you’ll have $f(x)=\exp(-ae^{2x})$ (the constant $c$ does not matter here as $f$ shows up only in ratios). For $T_0$ you should choose an element in the support of the distribution.

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean that, to a degree, $T_0$ can be chosen freely as long as it is in the support of the distribution ?

Comment: do we also choose $(U_n)$ and $(Z_n)$ to be two independent sequences of i.i.d. random variables such that $U_1\sim U(0,1)$ and $Z_1\sim N(0,1)$. Same $(U_n)$ and $(Z_n)$  regardless which type of distribution we will try to get ?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.